# matplotlib exact solution to a differential equation

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, differential-equations

I'm trying to plot the exact solution to a differential equation (a radioactive leak model) in python2.7 with matplotlib. When plotting the graph with Euler methods OR SciPy I get the expected results, but with the exact solution the output is a straight-line graph (should be logarithmic curve).

Here is my code:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#define parameters
r = 1
beta = 0.0864
x0 = 0
maxt = 100.0
tstep = 1.0

#Make arrays for time and radioactivity

t = np.zeros(1)

#Implementing model with Exact solution where Xact = Exact Solution
Xact = np.zeros(1)
e = math.exp(-(beta/t))
while (t[-1]<maxt):
    t = np.append(t,t[-1]+tstep)
    Xact = np.append(Xact,Xact[-1] + ((r/beta)+(x0-r/beta)*e))

#plot results
plt.plot(t, Xact,color="green")
```

I realise that my problem may be due to an incorrect equation, but I'd be very grateful if someone could point out an error in my code. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want `e` to depend on `t`, as in

```
 def e(t): return np.exp(-t/beta)
```

and then use

```
 Xact.append( (r/beta)+(x0-r/beta)*e(t[-1]) )
```

But you can have that all shorter as

```
t = np.arange(0, maxt+tstep/2, tstep)
plt.plot(t, (r/beta)+(x0-r/beta)*np.exp(-t/beta), color="green" )
```